# Use MFA with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Has anyone out there managed to get MFA to work in a sign-up policy in Azure AD B2C?

I've tried the sample described here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-api-dotnet/

But when I go through the sign-up process and click the Create button, I only get a blank page and not the second verification step with my mobile phone, which I guess is the expected result.

The URL I get redirected to is:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[myb2cdirectory].onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignupTest/api/SelfAsserted/confirmed?csrf_token=*longtoken*&tx=eyJUSUQiOiI0OTZiMzY4ZC03NDMxLTRjNTMtYjRmOS1iZDFmODEwZDJkY2UifQ&metrics=v1.0.1%3Bhttps%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fstatic%2Ftenant%2Fdefault%2FselfAsserted.cshtml%2C10%2C1%2C394%2C200%3B&p=B2C_1_SignupTest

Has anyone managed to get MFA to work with the sample or at all?

I wonder if I've missed some settings in my policy (besides enabling MFA...).

Thanks!

Erik

Answer (score 3):

I have performed following the article: [active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-api-dotnet](https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-api-dotnet/). It doesn't have the problem.

Please make sure you have not missed any vital steps:

- When you click "Application",enter a name, and toggle the **Include web app / web API** switch to Yes.
- The **Reply URLs** need a default url.
- And go to **Sign-up policies** add  page ,keyin name and Identity providers.
- Then **Run now** again